Update addresses for Google users via apps script
I have written a small script with which I can assign a new work address to a Google user via Google Apps Script. The script also runs without errors and if a value is already stored in the field for the work address, it is also deleted, but the new address is not transferred to the field and saved.
The values that are to be entered are also pulled from my GSheet without any problems.
When I check the field via the Google API checker, no values are stored after executing my script - before that they were.
Who has a tip for me as to where my error is?
Thanks in advance.
function myEditUserDatas() {
  var ssID = "1_yDRkyO9kwT-EPGLqJf99KBAb2-xxxx-xx-x-xx---xx";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("EditEmployees ");
  var myLR = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= myLR; i++) {
    var uMail = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(uMail);

    var CompanyAddress = sheet.getRange(i,18).getValue();
    user.addresses = [
      {streetAddress: 'Neue Straße 123',
        city: 'Musterstadt',
        region: 'BY',
        postalCode: '12345',
        country: 'Deutschland',
        type: 'work'}
    ];

    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, uMail);
  }
}


Is it correct for me to assume that uMail is a column containing email addresses (i.e. someone@gmail.com)?

Are you looking to update the work address of a user in your Admin console via the Admin Console SDK? If yes, then you'll need to convert your user.addresses to the formatted type as that seems to be the format of work addresses in the Admin Console. It won't really have an error since there's nothing "wrong" with the code, it's just that it's not getting saved due to a formatting issue.

Correct: uMai comes from my GSheet and is the eMail-address.

Update addresses for Google users
Your code is almost there, when I tried and checked it on the API CHECKER the data is posted, see the sample output below:



To get the data work I added some line of code to the code given.
function myEditUserDatas() {
  var ssID = '--Sheet ID--';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("--Sheet Name--");
  var myLR = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= myLR; i++) {
    var uMail = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(uMail);

    // var CompanyAddress = sheet.getRange(i,18).getValue();
    user.addresses = [
      {
        streetAddress: 'Neue Straße 123',
        city: 'Musterstadt',
        region: 'BY',
        postalCode: '12345',
        country: 'Deutschland',
        type: 'work'
      }
    ];
    

    // Use the formatted Method here.
    user.addresses[0].formatted = `${user.addresses[0].streetAddress}, ${user.addresses[0].city}, ${user.addresses[0].region}, ${user.addresses[0].postalCode}, ${user.addresses[0].country}, ${user.addresses[0].type}`;
    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, uMail);
  }
}

Sample Output:

The Data is also reflected in Admin Console in User Information.


Reference:

formatted



Many thanks for you helpful tipps. I solved it now with thisscript


function myEditUserDatas() {
  var ssID = "1_yDRkyO9kwT-EPGLqJf99KBAb2-xxxx-xx-x-xx---xx";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("EditEmployees ");
  var myLR = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 2; i <= myLR; i++) {
    var uMail = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(uMail);

    var CompanyAddress = sheet.getRange(i,18).getValue();
    user.addresses = [
      {type: 'work',
        "formatted": CompanyAddress}
    ];
    AdminDirectory.Users.update(user, uMail);
  }
}



